# How to fix "address boundary error" for the Android Emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am having problems starting the emulators currently - it worked before but not anymore:

```
✗ ~ /home/ligi/bin/android-sdk/emulator/emulator @29 -no-snapshot       14:34:10
emulator: Android emulator version 30.4.5.0 (build_id 7140946) (CL:N/A)
handleCpuAcceleration: feature check for hvf
cannot add library /home/ligi/bin/android-sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.so: failed
added library /home/ligi/bin/android-sdk/emulator/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.so
cannot add library /home/ligi/bin/android-sdk/emulator/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.so.1: full
emulator: INFO: GrpcServices.cpp:301: Started GRPC server at 127.0.0.1:8554, security: Local
emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered

fish: “/home/ligi/bin/android-sdk/emul…” terminated by signal SIGSEGV (Address boundary error)
```

Not really sure what changed. But I would love to be able to use the emulators again.